# angularJS get value from a textarea inside a ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs

How can I get the value of `textarea` inside a `ng-repeat`?

```
<div class="container" ng-repeat="data in dataList.dataCatalog | filter:{sea:season}">
        <img src="../content/catalog/{{season}}/{{ data.id }}" />
        <div class="containerDescription"> Desc : 
        <p>
        <textarea ng-model="textArea[$index]" style="height:120px; width:200px;">{{data.description}}
        </textarea>
        </p>
        <div ng-click="saveDescription(data.id,$index)">save</div>
        </div>
 </div>
```

..

```
  $scope.saveDescription = function (id,count) {
            description=$scope.textArea[count]
            alert(description)
        }
```

What is my mistake?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<div class="container" ng-repeat="data in dataList.dataCatalog | filter:{sea:season}">
        <img src="../content/catalog/{{season}}/{{ data.id }}" />
        <div class="containerDescription"> Desc : 
        <p>
        <textarea ng-model="textArea" style="height:120px; width:200px;">{{data.description}}
        </textarea>
        </p>
        <div ng-click="saveDescription(data.id,$index,textArea)">save</div>
        </div>
 </div>
```

No need to use an array. Just pass the text as a parameter to the function

```
 $scope.saveDescription = function (id,count,textArea) {
        description=textArea;
        alert(description)
    }
```

Comment: If i then wanted to clear that textarea how do I go about that as its not in the scope?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `data.description` directly as a model, and then pass data as a parameter for your `saveDescription()` callback.

Additionally when interpolating values in an image `src` attribute you can use the `ng-src` directive to handle un-interpolated values.

Furthermore, using `$index` in a filtered `ng-repeat` does not guarantee that it returns the correct `$index` of the original data, in this case: `dataList.dataCatalog`.

**[SEE THIS DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/jZM23zRpaMjA9JC1YtFy?p=preview)**

**HTML**

```
<div class="container" ng-repeat="data in dataList.dataCatalog | filter:{sea:season}">
        <img ng-src="../content/catalog/{{season}}/{{ data.id }}" />
        <div class="containerDescription"> Desc : 
        <p>
        <textarea ng-model="data.description" style="height:120px; width:200px;"></textarea>
        </p>
        <div ng-click="saveDescription(data)">save</div>
        </div>
 </div>
```

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
 $scope.saveDescription = function (data) {
     alert(data.id);
     alert(data.description);
 };
```